# How to find when a table being used last time in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have bunch of tables in a db spread across multiple schemas. I am sure that most of the tables are never used ( meaning they were created for backup ). I need to find out when each table was being used last time ( date and time ), and created and size. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Redshift does not keep track of "last time a table was used".

However, you could search through [STL_QUERY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) and [STL_QUERYTEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERYTEXT.html) to extract table names used in queries.

Be careful — these tables rotate after a period of time so they do *not* contain a complete history.